# Why does the routine continue in loops without stopping (ret)? [assembly]

Tags: assembly

I wrote a routine (as a part of a code), and it does not ret even when it has to ret.

this is the routine:

```
rout3:       lea SI,strtxt  ;put the array in indirect addressing register
             add SI,counter ;add a counter (starts from 0)
             mov CL,[SI]    ;move the character in counter location in the
                             array to CL register
             mov char,CL    ;move the character from the register to an operand
             inc counter      ;increase counter for the next character (next location)


             lea BX,arr ;new counter array (size: 256 ascii characters).
                         put the array in the register
             mov CL,char  ;instead of the counter, the ascii value of the
                           character is the location 
             add BX,CX   ; add the location (the ascii value- up to 256)
             inc [BX]    ;increase the value of the ascii location (in the array) by one

             mov CL,strlen  ;move the length of the first array (strtxt) to CL register
             cmp counter,CX   ;compare the currect location of the character
                               to the full length of it
             jb rout3         ;if the location is smaller than the strtxt array length, 
                               go to the next character. if not- ret.
             ret
```

I have a problem with the part of the `"jb rout 3"` and with the `ret`. Even when the counter is equal or bigger than the strlen (the length of the array), the routine restarts.
Please help me, it took me a long time to write the explanation of the code for your understanding when you help me.

Thank you and good day!

Comment: from what I can see JB uses 2 operands as per _The JB instruction branches to the address specified in the second operand if the value of the bit specified in the first operand is 1. The bit that is tested is not modified. No flags are affected by this instruction._ from [ 8051 Instruction Set Manual](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_jb.htm)

Comment: OK if not 8051 but 80x86 , which appears more likely. JB is jmp if below. It is perhaps unlikely that counter (starts at 0 and is incremented) will ever be below CX (never used 80x86 so not sure, but I suspect that is where the problem is).

Comment: @MikeT : Based on all the instructions this looks like 8086/8088

Comment: @Michael Petch yep added another comment for 80x86.

Comment: I recommend stepping through the code in a debugger and watch what happens.

Comment: Why do you switch from using CL to CX? What's in the high half of CX? Also, when does counter get set to zero?

Comment: @michael Petch- I stepped trough the code in a debugger and their value was equal, but the next step I did moved me again to rout3 and I didn't understand what was the problem.                 deltab- because strlen operand is db and the counter is dw, so I have to use 16 bit register. In CH there is nothing. The counter incremented by one every time.

Comment: ooops sorry missed out not, should read have read unlikely that counter will even **not** be below CX. Does debugger allow you to see CF? perhaps add line to subtract CX from counter and look at the result, as I believe that's basically what the compare does.

Answer (score 1):

This code is so inefficient it's hard to figure out what it's supposed to accomplish.  The comments describe what each instruction does on a really local level, but not what the overall goal is.

AFAICT, the loop should not be infinite.  `inc [counter]` / `cmp [counter],CX` will eventually result in a not-taken `jb`.  Assuming `counter` isn't being overwritten by anything else in the loop, and that `inc counter` is using a 16bit operand-size (thanks to your assembler seeing a `dw` directive following the label?), it will eventually reach `0xFFFF`, which can't be below any value that CX could have.

As was pointed out in comments, you never write `CH`.  You write `CL` and read `CX`.  If this routine is called with a non-zero value in `CH`, it will probably loop more times than you want it to.  You should probably `xor cx,cx` to zero it on entry to the function.

---

I don't understand why you don't just keep the counter in a register, and use different registers (like al/ah, dl/dh) for other temp values.

This sequence is particularly pointless:

```
mov char,CL
... a couple insns that don't touch CX
mov CL,char
```

Even if you did need to spill `CL`, you could have just reloaded it from `[SI]`, since you don't modify `[SI]`.  Or not loaded it in the first place until the point where it was needed.

---

Most functions with loops don't loop back to the function entry point, because it's much more efficient to do some setup outside the loop, so the loop itself can be tight (with few instructions and few loads/stores).

Comment: Thank you! I wrote the "xor CX,CX" and it helped a lot! The only problem is that even when it gets to "ret", it takes me to the "call rout3" again and then go trough the routine "rout3" one more time instead of going to the next line without going through the routine again. Do you know how could this happen?

Comment: @H.Bi: no idea, because you haven't posted the rest of your code.

Comment: hey, I fixed the problem I had. Now I have another problem so I opened a new question page with the rest of the code. If you can, please help me there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183130/the-output-is-not-displayed-in-its-entirety-8086-assembly Thank you!

Comment: @H.Bi: don't forgot to mark this answer as "accepted", with the checkbox under the up/down vote arrows, if you feel like it answers the question.