# The output is not displayed in its entirety [8086 assembly]

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
    ;The number of repetition of each character in the string


    .MODEL       small 
    .STACK       100h              
    .DATA

    msg3         db 13,10,'Enter a string up to 200 characters:$'         
    msg4         db       '      $'
    msg5         db 13,10,'Hit any key to exit',13,10,'$' 
    crlf         db 13,10,'$'           
    char         db 0
    repet        db 0
    mone1        dw 0  
    mone2        dw 0
    dig1         db 0
    dig2         db 0
    dig3         db 0 
    arr          db 256 dup(0)
    str          db 200
    strlen       db 0
    strtxt       db 200 dup(0)

    .CODE 

                 mov AX,@data
                 mov DS,AX

                 call GetString
                 call UpdateArr
                 call Repetitions
                 call EndProject
    GetString:   lea DX,msg3       ;Show msg3 on screen
                 mov AH,09h
                 int 21h

                 lea DX,str        ;Accept a string
                 mov AH,0ah
                 int 21h 

                 lea DX,crlf       ;New line for the output    
                 mov AH,09h
                 int 21h

    UpdateArr:   xor CX,CX         ;Nullify CX register
                 mov CL,strlen     
                 cmp mone1,CX      ;Compare the location of the character in str
                                    string to the full length of str 
                 jb  Below         ;If below, jump Below
                 ret

    Below:       lea SI,strtxt     ;Reach a character in str string
                 add SI,mone1     
                 mov CL,[SI]      
                 mov char,CL       ;Move the character from CL to char operand
                 inc mone1         ;Increase mone1 in one

                 lea BX,arr        ;Nullify CX register
                 mov CL,char
                 add BX,CX
                 inc [BX]          ;Increace the ascii value place of the character
                                    in arr counter array in one

                 jmp UpdateArr         

    Repetitions: lea BX,arr        ;Reach the several iterations of each ascii
                                    character
                 add BX,mone2
                 xor CX,CX
                 mov CL,[BX]
                 mov repet,CL      ;Move the several iterations from CL to repet
                                    operand
                 inc mone2

                 cmp repet,0       ;Compare repet to zero 
                 je Repetitions    ;If there is no repetition at all, jump to
                                    Repetitions

                 xor AX,AX         ;Nullify AX register
                 xor BX,BX         ;Nullify BX register

                 mov AL,repet
                 mov BL,10         ;Divide AL by 10, result in AL, rest in AH
                 div BL

                 mov dig3,AH       ;Move the rest of the devision in AH to dig3
                                    operand
                 mov AH,0          ;Nullify AH

                 mov BL,10         ;Divide the result in AL by 10, new result in AL,
                                    rest in AH
                 div BL

                 mov dig2,AH       ;Move the rest of the devision in AH to dig2
                                    operand
                 mov dig1,AL       ;Move the result of the devision in AL to dig1
                                    operand

                 add dig1,'0'      ;Change digit from binary to ascii
                 add dig2,'0'
                 add dig3,'0' 

                 lea BX,msg4       ;Put address of msg4 in BX
                 dec mone2         ;Decreace mone2 in one
                 mov AX,mone2      
                 mov [BX],AL       ;Put mone2 (the ascii character) in msg4 
                 inc mone2         ;Increace mone2 in one

                 mov AL,'('
                 mov [BX+1],AL     ;Put '(' in msg4

                 mov AL,dig1
                 mov [BX+2],AL     ;Put dig1 in msg4

                 mov AL,dig2
                 mov [BX+3],AL     ;Put dig2 in msg4

                 mov AL,dig3
                 mov [BX+4],AL     ;Put dig3 in msg4

                 mov AL,')'
                 mov [BX+5],AL     ;Put ')' in msg4

                 lea DX,msg4       ;Show output line msg4
                 mov AH,09h
                 int 21h

                 cmp mone2,256     ;Compare mone2 to 256
                 jle Repetitions   ;If not all the ascii characters were checked,
                                    jump to Repetitions

                 ret                  

    EndProject:  lea DX,msg5       ;show msg5 on screen 
                 mov AH,09h
                 int 21h     

                 mov AH,01h        ;read a char
                 int 21h

                 mov AH,4CH        ;end program
                 int 21h
                 ret
    END
```

The input is a string up to 200 characters ("str"). It goes on the string and increace the ascii value location of each character in the string in the counter array ("arr").
The output is the several iterations of each ascii character [256 characters (the length of the counter array)].
For example:

a(005)3(016)%(109)

The problem is that if I write more than five characters, it displays just five of them and not the rest (all of them).
What is the problem in the code?

**important detail-**

`mone1` means counter1 and `mone2` means counter2

Thank you!

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, and I didn't understand what is the source of the problem.

Comment: Out of curiousity does this code actually compile for you as you have posted it?

Comment: As I said, if I write more than 5 characters, the output is just 5 of them.

Comment: I know what you have said, but I ask again, have you actually been able to assemble the code that you actually posted here without error? For instance there are lines with comments that don't start with a semicolon `;`, the variable `str` conflicts with the _STR_ instruction, and the line `inc [BX]` doesn't specify a width, and I don't know how MASM/TASM would be able to guess the size. I'd think it would have to be `inc byte ptr [BX]`?? If this in fact compiles, I'd love to know what assembler (and assembler version) you are using.

Comment: @MichaelPetch it looks as if the uncommented lines are overflow from the line above, wrapped by the text editor but not surviving a copy/paste. But I agree about the `inc [BX]`, no operand size is given.

Comment: I feel like this code would be more readable if you made use of all the registers instead of keeping frequently-used things in memory.  The `Repetitions` loop is really hard to read, and doesn't have any function calls, so it could be *way* simpler.  There are several cases of comments not matching code: e.g. `;Nullify CX register` on a `lea BX,arr`.  Most of the comments are useless and don't add any new information for the reader.  You don't have to say that `inc` increments.  The line about what `mone1` and `mone2` are should be a comment inside the code, not just text outside the code.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that @WeatherVane (about the comments), was just bring it up. What I really missed in the question was the tag _EMU8086_ which will blindly default the `inc [bx]` to a byte and also explains why it had no issue with the  `STR` label.

Answer (score 1):

Your subroutine `GetString:` lacks a `ret` instruction. So it falls through to `UpdateArr:` which does return, but is then called again, so who knows what effect that has, I am not going to explore to see if it satisfies the observed behaviour.

Comment: In the end I realized that I had no problems at all but the only problem is that when the DOS screen is small, it shows all the output but when I enlarged the screen it didn't show all the output. Do you know why?